# Jquery: Check if sortable element has a child before a recieve happens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a paper doll inventory.  Like Diablo where you have elements and you drag armors onto your character.  The box the armor goes in is a sortable.  When it receives I need to know if the say "Armor" slot has an item already in it, so it can remove the one it in before receiving the new armor.

All Slots are the same class.

Would it be something like

```
$(".slot").sortable({
    receive: function(){
        $(this).parent().children();
    }
 });
```

OR

```
 $(this).sibling();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if an element has children with `$(this).children().length > 0`

for instance:

```
if ($(this).children().length > 0)
{
    //has children
}
{
    //childless
}
```

Comment: That would check the children of the receiving element.  "this" on receive is a pointer at the incoming event.

Comment: I don't know where you would bind it, I skimmed over the jquery-ui-sortable documentation but couldn't find an event with a reference to the area about to be dropped into.. :/